# How to translate multidimensional array from Javascript to C?

Tags: javascript, c

> I am currently working on translating code from JavaScript to C using the Raylib framework for game coding practice, and I came across the following code:

```
 area: {
        columns:8,
        map:[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
              0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4,
              0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0, 4,
              0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
              7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,13, 0,
              0,11,12, 9,10, 0, 0, 7,
              0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             12, 0,14,14,14, 0, 8, 0 ]
       }
```

> Since I work in C, I figured this is self explanatory because it looks like a multidimensional array. I found the column variable strange, so I ignored it (I'll come back to that later). Then, later in the JavaScript code, I see a function with the following:

```
var value  = area.map[row * area.columns + column];
```

> So, this is an object with two members; an int named 'column' and a multidimensional array named 'map'; I can make a struct. But, why does area.map[] only have one bracket, wasn't this supposed to be a multidimensional array? Which elements of the array are being manipulated here? Where's the other bracket? How would I translate this into C code to read the array?

Comment: Not sure why you're quoting yourself. If you look closely at that `map` property you'll see it's really a 1-dimensional array. You just have to do a tiny bit of math to convert a row and column number into an index into a 1 dimensional array, but you do need to know the # of columns for that, which is why that's a separate prop.

Comment: Thank you. I will start implementing this right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're after, but here is a translation into C

```
struct Area
{
  unsigned int columns;
  unsigned int map[];
};

struct Area area = {
  .columns = 8,
  .map     = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
               0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4,
               0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0, 4,
               0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,13, 0,
               0,11,12, 9,10, 0, 0, 7,
               0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
              12, 0,14,14,14, 0, 8, 0 }
};

unsigned int value = area.map[row * area.columns + column];
```

Comment: This was a one dimensional array all along? Wow. I totally missed that when looking at the code. Thank you. I was tired, up all night, and over-thinking this simple array.